# Get disk usage (load) in percentage with PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have a dedicated Linux server that is currently hosting a few games.
I recently started to code on a control panel written in PHP and I would like to be able to display the disk load in this control panel.

**How can I get the disk usage (load) in percentages using PHP under Linux?**

If it helps, I am the owner of this dedicated machine and I can install any packages you might suggest.

Comment: @Lanklaas that's for CPU usage, not disk usage

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// $df contains the number of bytes available on "/"
$df = disk_free_space("/");

// On Windows:
$df_c = disk_free_space("C:");
$df_d = disk_free_space("D:");
?>
```

Refer the below link for more details, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php

Comment: I'm not interested in showing the available space, I would like to know how much load my SSDs are under. Like `iostat` util%

Answer (score 0):

```
$mountedDirectory = "/";

$dts = disk_total_space($mountedDirectory );
$dfs = disk_free_space($mountedDirectory );

$usedPercent = round(($dts - $dfs) / $dts * 100)."%";
echo $usedPercent;
```

OUTPUT Used% RESULT